# Java Jung Graph constructor that takes a degree sequence

Tags: java, constructor, jung

I have been looking at the Jung Graph package [documentation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) for a constructor to create a graph given its degree sequence.

1. Does this functionality exist in Jung?
2. Is there an easy implementation for me to do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constructor, nor any graph generator implementations to do this, nor do we have any plans to provide such a capability.

Here is a link to some papers on the subject: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html

However, it's not obvious to me from the description there that any of the proofs (that a given sequence is valid) are constructive, i.e., that they provide a recipe for constructing a graph given a valid sequence.

What problem are you trying to solve?

(h/t Louis Wassermann for the link)